# Reading integers from file and initializing a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have this code which reads a specific file which has the values 22 and 14 respectively, and on the same line.

```
int main()
{
    int rows = 0;
    int column = 0;

    string line;
    ifstream file("Path To File"); 
    if(file.is_open()){ 
            getline(file, line);
            cout << line << endl;
        file.close();
    }
    else{ 
        cout << "File cannot be read." << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How can I create a multidimensional array which has the size of the integers I read from the file?

For example, if the file has 22 and 10, rows should = 22 and columns should = 10.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input file only contains the row and col values separated by a space, you can use stringstream to stream the line one word at a time to an int.

```
int rows, column;
std::string line;
std::ifstream file("Path To File"); 
if(file.is_open()){ 
    std::getline(file, line);
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
    std::stringstream( line ) >> rows >> column;
    file.close();
}
int matrix[ rows][ column ];
```

Edited to use std::stringstream instead of std::stoi

Comment: Do I need to #include something in order to use the std::stoi?

Comment: stoi was introduced in C++11. If your compiler doesn't support that use std::atoi( word.c_str() )

Comment: mmm, weird. If I use either it says "error: 'stoi' was not declared on this scope" or "error: 'atoi' was not declared on this scope"

Comment: Requires #include string. Otherwise #include <sstream> and then std::stringstream( word ) >> rows; A quick google will give many ways to convert string to an int

Comment: Alright, I managed to make it work. So it should look like this? It compiles with no errors.

if(file.is_open()){
            getline(file, linea);
            cout << linea << endl;
            string number;
            file >> number;
            stringstream(number) >> rows;
            file >> number;
            stringstream(number) >> columns;
    file.close();

    int matrix[rows][columns];
        file.close();
}

Comment: If you want to use getline then this will probably work better: getline(file, linea); cout << linea << endl; stringstream(linea) >> rows >> columns; file.close(); This has no error handling. If you want to use the matrix outside the if statement you'll have to declare it after the if statement ends, ie after the right brace.

Comment: Edited answer to use stringstreams

Answer (score 0):

Start with Brute Force and tune for performance as required.

```
Loop while std::getline can read a line from the file
    Write the line into a std::stringstream. 
    Make an empty std::vector. 
    Loop while >> can read a token from the std::stringstream
        Push the token into the std::vector. 
    Push the std::vector into a std::vector of std::vectors.
```

You may have to pad rows in the matrix with zeros if they are too short.